# How to remove X-powered-By in WebLogic Server and JBoss?

Tags: jboss, http-headers, weblogic

I am using JBoss version 7.1 and WebLogic. I want to remove it in both the cases.

I am able to see ***X-Powered-By*** in response header even though I am not setting it anywhere.

How do I remove it from Response header option in Network tab while debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

In the WebLogic console, click on the Domain, then the Web Applications tab. You will have an option called 'X-Powered-By Header'. Select the option called 'X-Powered-By header will not be sent'.

Comment: Actually I am using Struts 1.x to build my application. I want to configure it somewhere in the application so that it is server independent.Is it possible to do so??

Comment: No, because it is not your application that adds the response header, it is your servlet container.